# How to reinstall Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail safely?

Tags: installation

How can I reinstall Ubuntu 13.04 safely, without losing anything except settings? Is it possible? Or at least keep only programs and the home directory?

I want to reinstall as I have recently experienced various issues like the scrolling being very jumpy and lightdm rendering weirdly. Can someone more experienced explain how to reinstall Ubuntu as I have been searching in vain for days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Your problem is either in the settings, or in the binaries (program, libraries). The usual reason for reinstalling is to lose the system-wide settings. To reset user-specific settings, either create a new user, or delete all dot-files in your home. On the other hand, if your problem were not in the settings, it would be in a program or library, thus the only thing you could do would be to file a bug report. I cannot think of another reason to reinstall.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:  Re-Installing should not affect any of your documents but, just to be on the safe side, you should do a backup of your documents, including /home hidden files, using something like [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php)**

Boot your system from CD or bootable USB, and when you get to the installation screen, choose upgrade 13.04 with 13.04 if available, if not choose something else,

[image]

and when you get to the partitioning screen keep everything the same, and un-check the Format check-box.

[image]

For more info see the [Ubuntu Reinstallation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation) site

<sup>Source:[Ubuntu Reinstallation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation)</sup>

Comment: Not affect what settings?

Comment: That was a typo, I've removed it.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Generally when installing Ubuntu it's handy to have a separate /home partition for just such a problem that keeps all of your files and settings safe and lets you re-install the / filesystem...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it . Check the steps mentioned in the below site. It would be helpful to you.
[How to reinstall ubuntu without losing any thing](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-without-losing-the-old-data-with-separate-home-partition/)