# Unable to reinstall 13.04, option missing from LiveCD

Tags: installation, 13.04

I want to reinstall 13.04 over my current installation (while keeping my files). From various other questions here, there is supposed to be an option on the Live CD to "Reinstall Ubuntu 13.04" (as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317501/ubuntu-13-04-clean-install-over-other-ubuntu-13-04) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351071/ubuntu-installation-botched-up-and-now-it-wont-install)). Here is what I see:

[image]

I tried choosing "Something else" as suggested in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291376/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail-safely). I select the partition with my current Ubuntu installation on it, but then I get an error, "No root file system is defined". Here is the screen:

[image]

What am I missing here? How do I reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/80455/no-root-file-system-defined-error-while-installing-ubuntu

Comment: @Braiam so if I click 'Change' and set / as the mount point, that won't overwrite my home directory?

Comment: Probably, but you should had backups somewhere no ;).

Answer (score 0):

If you encrypted your files when you installed ubuntu you cant save your files.

Comment: No, not using any encryption.

Comment: maybe you can not remember. lock my home folder. when installing.

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you're saying...

Comment: http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/extra/LINUX/large/ubuntu1210installation-large_010.jpg

Comment: I don't remember that option when I first installed (which would have been 10.10 I think) but I would not have selected it if it was there.

Comment: only it. i dont know why you dont see "Reinstall".